# Using an OR statement inside an if function

Tags: r

I have some links that I would like to apply an `if` statement over. The `if` statement will `break` when it sees a link in another dataset.

Suppose I have the following:

```
linkToStopAt_1 = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/alella/calefaccion-parking-jardin-terraza-trastero-piscina/164324318/d?from=list"

linkToStopAt_2 = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/alella/calefaccion-parking-jardin-terraza-trastero-piscina/164313177/d?from=list"

linkToStopAt_3 = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/alella/calefaccion-parking-jardin-terraza-piscina/164295760/d?from=list"
```

Along with:

```
listOfLink = c("https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/alella/calefaccion-parking-jardin-terraza-trastero-piscina/164348201/d?from=list", 
"https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/alella/calefaccion-parking-jardin-terraza-trastero-piscina/164336155/d?from=list", 
"https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/alella/aire-acondicionado-terraza-no-amueblado/164327028/d?from=list", 
"https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/alella/aire-acondicionado-terraza-no-amueblado/164326907/d?from=list", 
"https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/alella/calefaccion-parking-jardin-terraza-piscina/164295760/d?from=list"
)
```

I am looking for a more compact version of the following:

```
  if(linkToStopAt_1 %in% listOfLink || linkToStopAt_2 %in% listOfLink || linkToStopAt_3 %in% listOfLink){
    print(paste("something here"))
  }
```

So, if one of the `linkToStopAt_N` occurs in `listOfLink` then we stop / print something. However, I want to expand the `OR` condition to `N`. The problem I face is I am applying a function over a set of links and I want the function the `break` at the first instance it sees a link it already has. It could be that some links are removed, so, the code currently re-collects all of the data again since it has not "seen" that link before, but it has, its just been removed. For instance, the following link `lintToStopAt_1`.

```
https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/alella/calefaccion-parking-jardin-terraza-trastero-piscina/164324318/d?from=list
```

Goes to a URL `"https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/alella/todas-las-zonas/l?propertyNotFound"`. So, if it sees `propertyNotFound` then skip and go to the next link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `any` with `mget` (`mget` is used if there are many 'linkToStopAt' objects created in the global env, thus we use it to compactly return the values in a `list`, then `unlist` to a vector) and check if there `any` from 'linkToStopAt' is `%in%` 'listOfLink'

```
if(any(unlist(mget(ls(pattern = "linkToStopAt"))) %in% listOfLink)) {

}
```

If it is from a data.frame column

```
if(any(as.character(unique(currentData$linkURL)[1:10]) %in% listOfLink)) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this works great. `linkToStopAt` is actually taken from a data frame, i.e. `linkToStopAt = as.character(unique(currentData$linkURL)[1:10])`. So, its not stored in the global environment. So, I can remove `unlist(mget(ls(pattern = "linkToStopAt"))`?

Comment: @user113156 yes, you can remove it.  It thought you had `At_1`, `At_2`, .. objects

Comment: Thanks alot! `At_1`, `At_2` was just for the reproducible example.